# Python socket server with selection

Tags: python, sockets

How do I make socket server(made in node js) with node selection like the  one shown below in node.js in python3 ?

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('pose', function(pose){
        io.emit('pose', pose);
        console.log(pose);
    });
});
http.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Socket.io Running');
});
```

Comment: you mean creating a `socketio` server in python3 ?

Comment: can you provide client side part, seems the code you given is correct !

Comment: The nodejs server does work. So, the error can't be in the client side.

Comment: Please use the new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41011823/replacing-nodejs-socet-io-server-with-a-python-server) for further discussions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what I needed to do, here's the sample code with [reference](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on('my event')
def test_message(message):
    emit('my response', {'data': 'got it!'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, port = 3000)
```